# PHP / Wordpress -> Automatically Mirror User Password Changes from Live to Staging Database

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, staging

On our Wordpress site, if a member resets their password, this will do so on our Live site, which is fine.

Their password on Staging, though, won't be changed. This means that when we push the Staging site live, their password will be overwritten.

We're hosted with Siteground, which has an 'Easy Push' to push the full Staging site to Live.

It *is* possible to exclude specific tables from the push, but I want to make this as robust as possible, so if this exclusion gets overlooked, it won't matter.

The password is the only field that I need to update in this manner.

Is it possible to achieve this with Wordpress and the setup we have?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Using [SiteGround's Advanced Push](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/staging/push/#Using_the_Advanced_Push), you can select which tables to push to Live.

There are so many things that can change on your Live site (comments, posts, settings, etc.), that I would rarely push any tables from Staging to Live.

Comment: Yeah... I was hoping I'd be able to avoid this but I may not be able to!